# How to slice a list into sublists with different length

Tags: python, list, sorting

Context: I want to make multiple word search grid

I have an Input of lines of text (containing string of numbers and letters) like this:

```
2           <--- tells how many grids/boxes 
3           <--- tells rows/length
4           <--- tells columns/width 
catt        <--\
aata        <--- letters that will fill the box
tatc        <--/
cat         <--- the word that will be search inside the box
5           <--- and repeat but start with the rows
5
gogog
ooooo
godog
ooooo
gogog
dog
```

all of that comes in one list as an input

However, I need to pass variables inside. so I assume that I need to split/slice the list into another lists containing all variables that I need.

I think I need to split the variables for `cat` and `dog` like this:

```
#variables for cat and dog
rows, cols = [3, 5], [4, 5] #the numbers have to be integer
matrix = [['catt', 'aata', 'tatc'], ['gogog', 'ooooo', 'godog', 'ooooo', 'gogog']]
word = ['cat', 'dog']
```

those are the variables I need. but I don't know how to split it like that from the input above.

If there are any different ways, feel free to explain. Thank you

Comment: "cattaatatatc" For a second there I thought this was DNA. But then a dog showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `next` to iterate through a file object:

```py
with open('input.txt') as f:
    n_animal = int(next(f).strip())
    rows, cols, matrices, words = [], [], [], []
    for _ in range(n_animals):
        n_row = int(next(f).strip())
        n_col = int(next(f).strip())
        rows.append(n_row)
        cols.append(n_col)
        matrix = [list(next(f).strip()) for _ in range(n_row)]
        matrices.append(matrix)
        words.append(next(f).strip())

print('rows, cols = ', rows, cols)
print('matrices = ', matrices)
print('words = ', words)

# rows, cols =  [3, 5] [4, 5]
# matrices =  [[['c', 'a', 't', 't'], ['a', 'a', 't', 'a'], ['t', 'a', 't', 'c']], [['g', 'o', 'g', 'o', 'g'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['g', 'o', 'd', 'o', 'g'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['g', 'o', 'g', 'o', 'g']]]
# words =  ['cat', 'dog']
```

Note: if a list of strings is okay instead of a list of lists, then you can replace the `matrix =` line:

```py
# list of lists
matrix = [list(next(f).strip()) for _ in range(n_row)]

# list of strings
matrix = [next(f).strip() for _ in range(n_row)]
```

If your input is already stored as a list of strings, rather than as a file to read from, you can still use `next` on an iterator:

```py
lines = ['2', '3', '4', 'catt', ...]

f = iter(lines)

n_animal = int(next(f).strip())
rows, cols, matrices, words = [], [], [], []
for _ in range(n_animals):
    n_row = int(next(f).strip())
    n_col = int(next(f).strip())
    rows.append(n_row)
    cols.append(n_col)
    matrix = [list(next(f).strip()) for _ in range(n_row)]
    matrices.append(matrix)
    words.append(next(f).strip())
```

Comment: good answer btw, but what if I want to make the `matrices` be like this `[['catt', 'aata', 'tatc'], ['gogog', 'ooooo', 'godog', 'ooooo', 'gogog']]` . I tried `splitlines()` but the output be like this `[[['catt'], ['aata'], ['tatc']], [['gogog'], ['ooooo'], ['godog'], ['ooooo'], ['gogog']]]` . maybe you can help :)

Comment: @GilangArindawa I don't know what you mean by "I tried splitlines()". I'm not getting the same result as you. Did you try with `matrix = [next(f).strip() for _ in range(n_row)]` instead of `matrix = [list(next(f).strip()) for _ in range(n_row)]`?

Comment: wow that's well spotted, I didn't think of that lol. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

I have saved your input in a file called "input.txt" and used the following approach:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

n_animals, other_lines = int(lines[0]), lines[1:]

rows, cols, matrix, word = [[] for _ in range(4)] # comment by @Stef - well spotted

while len(other_lines) > 0:
    rows.append(int(other_lines[0]))
    cols.append(int(other_lines[1]))
    matrix.append(list(map(lambda x: x[:cols[-1]], other_lines[2:2 + rows[-1]])))
    word.append(other_lines[2 + rows[-1]])
    other_lines = other_lines[2 + rows[-1] + 1:]
    if len(matrix) == n_animals:
        pass # Do we need to take any action here? like break?

print(rows)
print(cols)
print(matrix)
print(word)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[3, 5]
[4, 5]
[['catt', 'aata', 'tatc'], ['gogog', 'ooooo', 'godog', 'ooooo', 'gogog']]
['cat', 'dog']
```

My assumption was that you want to do something with that *width* variable, hence I have cut every word to `cols[-1]` characters. Now, you need to decide what to do if `len(matrix) > n_animals`.

**FOLLOW UP**

Incorporating some feedback for efficiency:

```
i = 0
while i < len(other_lines):
    rows.append(int(other_lines[i]))
    cols.append(int(other_lines[i + 1]))
    matrix.append(list(map(lambda x: x[:cols[-1]], other_lines[i + 2 : i + 2 + rows[-1]])))
    word.append(other_lines[i + 2 + rows[-1]])
    i += 2 + rows[-1] + 1
    if len(matrix) == n_animals:
        pass # Do we need to take any action here? like break?
```

Comment: `rows, cols, matrix, word = [[]] * 4` Are you sure about that? Don't you want `rows, cols, matrix, word = [[] for _ in range(4)]` instead? Otherwise it's four times the same empty list and when you start modifying one of the empty lists, weird stuff happens.

Comment: @Stef well spotted. I got carried away because I had `rows, cols, matrix, word = [], [], [], []` but the way proposed is wrong. I will incorporate your input.  +1

Comment: Also `other_lines = other_lines[2 + rows[-1] + 1:]` in the while-loop is actually very costly; at every iteration of the while-loop you're copying all the remainder of the lines; so the total complexity is quadratic instead of linear. To circumvent that problem, you could either use an index `i`, writing `rows.append(int(other_lines[i]))`, instead of repeatedly slicing the list; or you could use an iterator with `next` instead of a list.

Comment: Also, the stopping condition for the main loop should be based on `n_animals`!

Comment: @Stef well I do not know the use case to conclude that. Should I stop if I reach the `n_animals` or should I do something else - in case more animals than expected are specified? What is 3 animals are expected and only 2 specified? Also because - in the specified example - `n_animals` is a redundant variable anyway.

Comment: @Stef can you give example about using index `i` like you said?

Comment: @nikeros What if the input is read from standard input rather than from a file? Then there is no end of file, and you want to stop asking for input once you've counter the correct number of animals.

Comment: @Stef *all of that comes in one list as an input* - my interpretation is that it is not line by line

Answer (score 0):

If the position of the information in each line is always 'fixed', then the easiest option is to convert the lines to a list, and then reference each line specifically. Something like:

```
data = text.splitlines()
grids = data[0]
rows = data[1]
cols = data[2]
letters = data[3:7]
repeat = data[7:9]
remain = data[9:]

print(grids, rows, cols, letters, repeat, remain)
```

Comment: it's not fixed. the number of times to repeat is given by the integer written at `data[0]`. Then the number of rows of letters is given at data[i+1], where i is the number of times you've repeated.